# Like Feature in Display Form on Sharepoint 2013 list item

Tags: display-form, rating, like

Is there a way to recreate the Like rating system from a SharePoint list view and insert this into the Display Form.

The display form contains the number of likes column by default, but doesn't give an option to like directly from the form.

I've seen something similar for the 1-5 ratings ([Rating Feature in Display Form SharePoint 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/199568/rating-feature-in-display-form-sharepoint-2013)) - but was unsure on how to amend this for Likes

Answer (score -1):

If you enable "Rating feature" on list, the rating field is automatically displayed on display form.

Comment: Yes, **displayed**, but still won't provide the _option to like_ as requested.